# Sqlite query to gets sum values of hours time bands

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table :

```
------------------------------------   
DATEHOUR         | FRUITS
------------------------------------ 
2020-11-24 00:00 | 10 
2020-11-24 00:15 | 10 
2020-11-24 01:00 | 30
2020-11-24 01:15 | 10 
2020-11-24 02:00 | 30
2020-11-24 02:15 | 10 
2020-11-25 00:00 | 30
2020-11-25 00:15 | 10 
2020-11-25 01:00 | 30
2020-11-25 01:15 | 10 
2020-11-25 02:00 | 30
2020-11-25 00:15 | 10 
------------------------------------
```

I need to calculate the SUM of FRUITS each DAYS grouped by bands, the first band (B1) is between 00:00 AND 01:00 , the sencond (B2) is between 01:15 AND 02:00

```
DAY        | B1  | B2  
------------------------
2020-11-24 | 50  | 60 
2020-11-25 | 40  | 80
```

Is it possible to do this with a simple SQL query ? I'm using SQLITE

Thanks

Comment: The answer that you accepted will return wrong results when the time is 01:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Given the structure of the first column, string functions are sufficient for the pivoting logic:

```
select substr(datehour, 10) as day,
       sum(case when substr(datehour, 12, 2) = '00' then fruits else 0 end) as hour_00,
       sum(case when substr(datehour, 12, 2) = '01' then fruits else 0 end) as hour_01
from t
group by day;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [SQLite's datetime functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(DATEHOUR) DAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TIME(DATEHOUR) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '01:00:00' THEN FRUITS END) B1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TIME(DATEHOUR) BETWEEN '01:15:00' AND '02:00:00' THEN FRUITS END) B2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY DAY
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ad7296e4513c29e877a10a3cac671812).
Results:

```
> DAY        | B1 | B2
> :--------- | -: | -:
> 2020-11-24 | 50 | 40
> 2020-11-25 | 80 | 40
```